# UTC=no in /etc/default/rcS on a Fresh Install 14.04. Why?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation, time

I recently installed 14.04, and decided to do so as a fresh install.

I wiped the only Ubuntu installation on the system, left a Windows 7 installation on, and installed over mdadm (once with /boot on mdadm and later with it not on mdadm as that saves a few other headaches. I'm pretty sure what I'm describing happened in both cases).

Everything from previous Ubuntu installations were completely wiped by manual formatting of the relevant partitions.

I'm in a time-zone currently on Irish Summer Time (UTC+01:00). Windows started jumping the time an hour ahead.

Now, I might expect a default Windows installation to jump the time an hour back, thinking the UTC bios time was the local time, but this was an hour ahead and I had `RealTimeIsUniversal` set in the registry to get some saner behaviour out of Windows.

After some puzzling over this, I realised that in /etc/default/rcS there was the line `UTC=no` to set Ubuntu onto local time rather than the normal `UTC=yes`.

This is a well-known setting for people who normally only use Windows as the illogical choice of local time (not unambiguous) means less change for them than fixing Windows in a way that MS don't support, but I certainly didn't set it.

This was easily fixed, but as I don't know what broke it, I don't know that it won't be broken again.

Is there anything that sets `UTC=no` upon use or installation, and if so can that be blocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install Ubuntu on a clean disk with no other OS, UTC=yes is used as default. In your situation, you have Windows aside Ubuntu. So in the installation Ubuntu detected Windows and set UTC=no. Although your Ubuntu is clean, the disk is not clean.

Comment: Well, that's pretty uselss if it's true. Does the same thing happen if there's a mix of Win and Linux?

Comment: @JonHanna I think it's a compromise. As Win and Linux have different time switching, you have to choose one as default.

Comment: which I had done. It decided to do what most linuxes do not do, and I can't see that choice documented anywhere.